# Newrelic agent tracing failure with `Invalid segment '<unknown>': start time (#####) after stop time (0)`

Tags: yii2, php-7, newrelic

I'm trying to integrate Newrelic into a Yii2 application and it seems there is some issues in capturing some transactions/traces, especially if they take longer.

From /var/log/newrelic/php_agent.log

```
2019-11-06 14:28:53.243 +0000 (42171 42171) warning: Invalid segment '<unknown>': start time (10097053) after stop time (0)
2019-11-06 14:28:53.243 +0000 (42171 42171) warning: Invalid segment '<unknown>': start time (10424999) after stop time (0)
2019-11-06 14:28:53.243 +0000 (42171 42171) warning: Segment iteration failed; no trace or span events will be generated for this transaction
```

From /var/log/newrelic/newrelic-daemon.log

```
2019/11/06 14:01:11.380047 (45) Info: Reporting to: https://rpm.eu.newrelic.com/accounts/###/applications/###
2019/11/06 14:01:11.380571 (45) Info: app 'local-rest-api' connected with run id 'BMay...waQ'
2019/11/06 14:50:08.040596 (45) Info: removing "local-rest-api" with run id "BMay...waQ" for lack of activity within 10m0s
2019/11/06 14:50:08.046068 (45) Info: removing "local-rest-api" with run id "BMay...waQ" for lack of activity within 10m0s
```

### Other env details:

- Docker 2.1.0.4 running on MacOS
- FROM php:7.2.14-fpm with Xdebug v2.7.2
- New Relic daemon version 9.2.0.247-51143810a9c6
- Yii2 v2.0.14

### Install script in docker:

```
RUN \
  curl -L "https://download.newrelic.com/php_agent/release/newrelic-php5-9.2.0.247-linux.tar.gz" | tar -C /tmp -zx && \
   export NR_INSTALL_USE_CP_NOT_LN=1 && \
    export NR_INSTALL_SILENT=1 && \
     /tmp/newrelic-php5-*/newrelic-install install && \
      rm -rf /tmp/newrelic-php5-* /tmp/nrinstall* && \
        sed -i -e 's/"REPLACE_WITH_REAL_KEY"/"xxxxxxxxxxxx"/' \
     -e 's/newrelic.appname = "PHP Application"/newrelic.appname = "local-rest-api"/' \
         /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/newrelic.ini
```

### Current workaround:

Adding `newrelic_end_of_transaction()` before `yii\base\Application::run()` ends, but it doesn't work for longer transactions (e.g. even if I add a 10s sleep).

Any suggestions on how to solve or further debug the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in Symfony, ekino/EkinoNewRelicBundle. Due to misconfiguration on my side, an extra newrelic_end_transaction() was called on every http request and produced the same error as you experience.

Maybe that helps to solve the problem - by avoiding too much transaction-ending